# Viewing x_range attributes on a Bokeh figure object?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to fix an older example for Bokeh where this no longer works:

```
callback = CustomJS(code="console.log('stuff')")
fig.x_range.callback = callback
```

Now this seems to be the solution:

```
callback = CustomJS(code="console.log('stuff')")
plot.x_range.js_on_change('start', callback)
```

How do I check what other attributes are there on the `x_range` object, other than `start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bokeh.models import DataRange1d

print(DataRange1d.properties())
```